# Pre-configured CakePHP with common things like authentication

Tags: php, cakephp

Has anyone come across a CakePHP system with pre-configured things like authentication with all the login/logout forms, etc? Most websites have some sort of a basic authentication system on top of which everything is built. I was hoping to not go about re-inventing the wheel setting up the most common pages like login, logout, forgot-password. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

CakePHP Cookbook is a good place to start. There is a sample aplication with the authentication stuff done:

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1543/Simple-Acl-controlled-Application

Answer (score 0):

How about you build it the way you want and then *reuse* that in all of your projects.

It's what I do and it is very much in the spirit of OO and MVC.

In no time at all you'll have your own library of modules/functions or whatever you want to call them.

Answer (score 0):

[PoundCake Control Panel](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bancer/) plugin

Answer (score 0):

You might find [Infinitas](https://www.ohloh.net/p/infinitas) interesting. It's a full CMS, but you can probably trim out the core functionality and use that since it's under an MIT license. The names of the main people developing it (ceeram and dogmatic69) are responsible for some of the more interesting (to me) bugs and fixes in the [CakePHP bug tracker](http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648-cakephp/tickets). This implies that they understand the internals of the framework pretty well.

Try it out and let us know in a comment if it'll function for what you need.